# Java - if statement keeps looping

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm having a little problem with getting my if statement to work. The scenario is that the user should be able enter 1 if they want British teams or 2 if they want American teams. Once they pick a region a list of teams will appear and they enter the number of team and the information of that team should print out but for some reason it just keeps looping and asks to enter a team. I have simplified my code slightly for here otherwise it would be too big.

```
ArrayList<STeam> teams = rCSV.readSTeams("sports-teams.csv");
Scanner UInput = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter 1 for British teams or 2 for American teams");
int choice = UInput.nextInt();
for (STeams st1 : teams) {

    if (choice == 1) {
        System.out.println("Choose: 1. London FC");
        int choice2 = UInput.nextInt();
        {
            if (choice2 == 1) {
                if (st1.getName().equals("London FC")) {
                    System.out.println(st1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (choice == 2) {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

Apologies if this is extremely messy.
I have a separate class that reads the file and a separate class for the sports teams and I know these work as I have done something similar like this but with only using 1 if statement within another instead of 2.

Comment: I have added the brackets for the 'for' but it still seems to keep asking me to enter a team number.

Comment: Can you post the `STeam` class?

Answer (score 0):

`choice` is never updated in your for loop.

You probably want to do:

```
for (STeams st1 : teams) {
    int choice = UInput.nextInt();
    if(choice == 1) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using this `for (STeams st1: teams)` which might be a left over code. Since it has no brackets the for will continuously loop over this.

---

EDIT: Ok, you probably want something like this:

ArrayList britishTeams = rCSV.readSTeams("sports-teams.csv");
        Scanner UInput = new Scanner(System.in);

```
    System.out.println("Enter 1 for British teams or 2 for American teams");
    int choice = UInput.nextInt();

    if (choice == 1) 
    {
        for(int option = 0; option<britishTeams.size; option++)
            System.out.println("Option " + option + ": " + britishTeams.get(option).name);    
        int choice2 = UInput.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You chose: " + britishTeams.get(choice2).name);   
    }
```

To add the american team, DONT copy/paste this all over again, make the code that takes a list of teams and chooses one a method ;-)

Comment: One question on your update: why are you iterating over the teams at all? Don't you want to just pick either american or british? What is in your STeam class?

Comment: The user picks american then british, then they choose which team they want. E.g I enter 2 for american then I enter 1 for a team called 'Lakers'.

Comment: OK, so the teams array includes both american and british teams and you want to filter them out?

Comment: Yes kind of but there are 2 arrays but to make this easier I only included 1 in the code above which was the british one. There are 2 files, one for british and one for american which are read and put into arrays. But I want to filter the file by the different teams.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Looks like you are running loop without any condition. So it will run till there are tokens in your teams. You need to use break once you are done with your selection.